# Specks of Vanilla Settling to the Bottom of Panna Cotta

Tags: baking, vanilla

Recently I made a Panna Cotta and although it was delicious, the vanilla I used had settled into a layer at the bottom of the dish. This wasn't an issue

How would we be able to more evenly disperse the vanilla to create

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate but the answers here might help you: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/119739/how-can-i-prevent-vanilla-seeds-from-sinking-in-a-cr%C3%A8me-br%C3%BBl%C3%A9e

Comment: As a panna cotta is a gelled dish, you would need to chill it partially so it begins to thicken, stir, and then fill your molds.  But it’s tricky because if you let it set too much you won’t get a smooth result (trapped bubbles or it doesn’t pour well as it’s more glop than liquid).  See my notes at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/54070/67 .  The critical temperature likely won’t be the same (you’re dealing with an opaque liquid so small bubbles aren’t a deal breaker, but you also have milk proteins and I don’t know how that changes things)